# Launcher missing after installing nVidia driver

Tags: nvidia, launcher

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and installed nVidia driver 'current'.
But on restart, the launcher icons went missing. The screen size reduced to 1024x768.
I am able to right click on the blank desktop and create a folder and an empty document, but how do I launch applications to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to type Alt + F2, search for "Software sources" go to "Additional drivers" tab and select driver for your nVidia. 
Restart computer and may work.
Worked for me.

Comment: The Dash meaning the left-hand side launcher ?

Comment: Yes, try to run dash by typing Alt + F2

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. But Im still going to re-install Ubuntu for another reason.

Comment: I re-installed Ubuntu and installed the nVidia driver. This time ALT+F2 doesn't pop up anything.

Comment: Windows button ?

Comment: Nope - nothing happens.