# Launcher still missing after installing nVidia driver

Tags: nvidia

I've asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220151/launcher-missing-after-installing-nvidia-driver) before but I'm still stuck. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new computer with 2GB nVidia Graphics card. I installed the 'current driver' but on restart I get a blank desktop. The launcher is missing. I can tty though. But I don't know what to do from there.
ALT + F2 doesn't bring up anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like you can still use nautilus (right click on the desktop, create folders and stuff) just the unity desktop is missing?

give us the output of:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
```

[ its probably just the missing of linux-headers-generic , remove all the drivers, install it, and get the drivers with additional drivers (jockey) again. but to be sure i need to know your output ]

~spheniscida

Comment: There is a slight problem though - the keyboard layout has changed as result I'm not to able to type |. I typed lspci -nnk and the last few lines shows "Subsytem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0915] Kernel Modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

Comment: okay, this does look like the problem i had, installing 'linux-headers-generic' and reinstalling the drivers should solve it, and i suggest you try it, in case of failure go for the next answer. (because its not as easy)
and mind telling us what graphic card model it exactly is?

Comment: I am using GE Force GT 610. I installed linux-headers-generic and did apt-get update and on a cold reboot, it started working. Frankly speaking I don't know what or how it got working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the nVida drivers with Ubuntu 12.04 - certain nVida graphics adaptors will not work. I have one of these, a GE Force 610GT.

Through a number of posts, I have found a process that reliably installs the updated nVidia drivers that do work very well with the nVidia drivers. You will need your Ubuntu installation CD.

If you go to this web-page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/fballem/Software%2012.04, you will see a set of instructions for installation of Ubuntu 12.04

If you put your CD in and reboot your system, you should be able to pickup the instructions at Step 6. This should allow you to install the correct drivers on your system. Please read the instructions carefully so that you understand what they are doing.

I hope this helps,